# Docker stack deploy: unable to set dnsrr as ports are exposed as ingress

Tags: docker, ports

When launching services using stack deploy we get the following error:

> "Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = 3 desc = EndpointSpec:
>   port published with ingress mode can't be used with dnsrr mode"

Testing has led me to try:
manually creating a network with `ignress=false` set, launching the stack deploy without exposing ports and joining the nodes to the network, then manually exposing ports.

```
docker service update --publish-add 5672:5672 service_name1
```

but still get the same error.

any thoughts?

Comment: Post all the commands that you have used and also errors that you receive with them. Dockerfile of the service also may help

Comment: Take a look to this post, it may have some useful info: [link](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25016)

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: No, resigned ourselves that CE just wasnt updated enough to cope with the requirements so we have gone to EE with a lot more success.

Answer (score 20):

For services with endpoint-mode set to **dnsrr** ports can't be published with the default mode which is 'ingress'. Changing the publish mode to **host** should work.

```
docker service update --publish-add published=80,target=80,protocol=tcp,mode=host service_name
```

In compose file it would be like,

```
ports:
  - target: 80
    published: 80
    protocol: tcp
    mode: host
```

Answer (score 0):

Exposing the port can be achieved by following these 2 commands:-

```
docker service update service_name1 --endpoint-mode=vip
docker service update --publish-add 5672:5672 service_name1
```

This will change endpoint mode to vip from dnsrr and later you can expose port with the same command

Comment: It might be not obvious from the question, but [endpoint mode](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#endpoint_mode) must have the opposite value: `--endpoint-mode=dnsrr`. And that mode [conflicts with exposed ports](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25016#issuecomment-500777446).